# Learning Curve in OpenGL vs Direct3D + other game components

Tags: opengl, comparison, directx, direct3d

Not to start a flame war....
but i am in chapter 4 of the OpenGL superbible and the books organization is NOT helpful for a beginner,
*I've been doing a little research on the backstory of each API also but a lot of fingers are pointing towards Direct3D as the future easier API considering their ability to actually progress, add new features and get them out there.*

Mainly though, i'm wondering if either have a steeper learning curve since i'm finding OpenGL pretty hard to get going with using my book...

**Should I switch to Direct3D if it's easier to learn, and maybe return to OpenGL later if they get going and catch back up to Direct3D again?**

by the way i'm hping to learn this stuff in context of studying C++ for a year and future game programming so i would also need to figure out how to get audio, ai, etc set up later too.....

**Thanks!!** =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you switch to Direct3D? Ask yourself the following questions:

- Do you want to be bound to developing for Windows only? [YES/NO]
- Are you ready to invest time learning a new API design every time the major version of the API increases? [YES/NO]
- Are you okay if new GPU generations' capabilities are available to you only with some major delay until the next major version of the API is released? [YES/NO]

If you answered any of the above with YES, then Direct3D is the right choice. Otherwise I recommend OpenGL:

- OpenGL is available on all major operating systems and plattforms as well as on more obscure ones.
- OpenGL's API design is astonishing stable, the basic principles have not changed over a decade. Take a look at the open source game *Nexuiz Classic*, which is largely based on the Darkplaces engine which is a overhaul of the open sourced Quake2 engine (written for OpenGL-1.1) and has been updated to support all modern whistles and bells of shader based rendering.
- OpenGL's extension mechanism allows GPU vendors to give access to newest generations' capabilites at release date. With Direct3D you're forced to wait until the next version is released by Microsoft. When NVidia released their GeForce8800 in 2006 it took half a year until Joe Average Developer could write Direct3D code for its new features. However through OpenGL extensions it was immediately accessible for OpenGL programs; I remember the day I bought my GeForce8800 (4 days after official release) built it into my machine and started hacking away with the geometry shaders the same evening.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you have most of this backwards.

OpenGL is definitely easier to learn than Direct3D -- in particular, you can use immediate mode for simple stuff where you don't care a lot about performance, and delay dealing with vertex buffers and pixel buffers, and so on.

OpenGL used to have a significant performance disadvantage compared to Direct3D, and relatively slow progress in adding new features. New development was turned over to Khronos a while back. While there's some controversy about some steps Khronos has taken, they have done quite well at feature parity, and it's been a few years since I've seen any real performance advantage for Direct3D either.